# Why does target-counter report the last page number instead of the first page the anchor appears in

Tags: itext, html2pdf

We have a case where content inside a div with given anchor/id spreads over different pages.

While retrieving the page number via css using this via a defined style

```
content: target-counter(attr(href), page);
```

It resolves to the last page number the content extends over, while for example building a table of contents you expect it to be the 1st page on which the referenced target occurs.

Doing some research points us to the following method where it goes wrong: com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TargetCounterHandler.addPageByID(IRenderer)

Subsequent pages for a given page id overwrite the tracked page number, which is then used by the logic to inject it in the content later on.

Answer (score 0):

We have applied following fix to test our assumptions, which makes it work but preferably a better solution is available?

```
    public static void addPageByID(IRenderer renderer) {
        final String id = renderer.<String>getProperty(Property.ID);
        if (id != null) {
            final TargetCounterHandler targetCounterHandler = getTargetCounterHandler(renderer);
            if (targetCounterHandler != null && renderer.getOccupiedArea() != null) {
                final int currentPageNumber = renderer.getOccupiedArea().getPageNumber();
                
                // Make sure to track the 1st occurrence of the page
                // otherwise we create page references in TOCs to the last one who passed by here
                Integer storedPageNumber = targetCounterHandler.renderersPages.get(id);
                if(storedPageNumber==null || storedPageNumber>currentPageNumber) {
                    targetCounterHandler.renderersPages.put(id, currentPageNumber); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```